# How to check if a field is sent by a spout or by a bolt?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I'm working with apache storm, and trying to make make sure if a field is created by a spout (I have many) and sent by bolts. The idea is simply to follow up to where it's defined to then get rid of it.

So in my spout I've overridden the

```
emit(List<Object> tuple, Object messageId)
```

method in order to increment a counter, my problem is that I need to access the name of the fields.

How can I access the names defined by the

```
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("test"));
}
```

method in the same spout/bolt?

I believe it's simple but I cannot find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understand your question completely. However, Storm does not provide any mechanism to access the declares output fields of a Spout/Bolt in the same Spout/Bolt. And I actually don't understand why you would need this? If you implement a Spout/Bolt, you actually know what field got declared anyway...

Of course, you could implement an own `OutputFieldsDeclarer` and call `this.declareOutputFields(myDeclarer)` and store the declared fields in `myDeclarer` to "access" them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a topology, you will give a name to each of spouts and bolts. So when you receive any tuple in the execute method from spout or bolt, invoke

```
input.getSourceComponent();
```

this will return you the name of the component, you can easily identify spout or bolt.

***How can I access the names defined***

To access the name of the field, you can say

```
tuple.getValueByField("test"));
```